# Error in connecting to localhost using URL java

Tags: java, sockets, url, networking, io

```
 try {
        URL u = new URL("http://[::1]/index.php");
        InputStream in = u.openStream();    
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.write(b);
        }
       }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
```

**returns**

> run: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect BUILD
>   SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Why it is throwing error? how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a server running on your localhost and listening to port 80, if not you get the connection refused error..